# What is the correct way to set an AD user country?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have to maintain a PowerShell script which transfer the employees informations from our database into our Active Directory.
This script runs every night automatically with elevated rights that I do not posess. In other words, I cannot "test" the script. To run the script, I have to commit my changes and create a PR that will trigger a deployment when accepted and wait until the next morning to see if it worked.
The informations are usually updated without any problems, except for the country. I tried updating the fields **countryCode**, **c** and **co** and it didn't work because we received an error like "value was not in the acceptable range...". Apparently this error happens when you try to update one of these 3 fields separately.
I found [how to update them all at once](https://www.adamfowlerit.com/2017/05/updating-country-field-active-directory/) and I was going to make the changes but I was surprised to discover that there is another field called **Country**.
I have a few questions :

1. Why does that Country field even exist ? Aren't **countryCode**, **c** and **co** enough ?
2. Should I update **Country** or should I update the **countryCode**, **c** and **co** ?
3. Why are there **4** different fields in the AD just to hold the country ?

I'd like to know more about this because I really want to get this right on the second try (the first one failed, hence why I'm here) Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: While this is interesting a question, it's not about programming and thus off-topic at Stack Overflow. Try asking at, say, [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com) instead.

Comment: `Country` is the property name PowerShell uses. The LDAP name for that same property is `c`. The string content of this attribute should be the [2 character abbreviation of the country](https://dovestones.com/country-codes-used-in-active-directory/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does that Country field even exist ? Aren't countryCode, c and co enough ?

It **doesn't** actually exist - the `Country` property exposed by the `ActiveDirectory` module maps directly to the `c` attribute in the AD schema - it's just an alias.

---

> Should I update Country or should I update the `countryCode`, `c` and `co`?

Given the answer above, no, you don't need to set `Country` when you set `c`.

---

> Why are there 4 different fields in the AD just to hold the country ?

As we've established, there are only 3:

- `c` is part of LDAPv3 specification (see [RFC2256](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2256)) to ensure compatibility with X500 DITs.
- `co` was (to my best knowledge) included in the original schema for NT domains for the same reason
- `countryCode` was introduced in the AD schema to help administrative tools enforce input validation of country names - unlike `co`, it's an enumeration type, and tools like "Active Directory Users and Computers" populate the Country dropdown with the possible enumeration values and then sets all three fields based on the chosen values

Comment: Oh ok so it's just an alias. Thank you ! I'll mark this as answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have null values for the users you need to change the country to, it worked for me like this, hope this helps somebody, it gave me some headaches until I figured it out.

```
$users = get-aduser -SearchBase "ou=RandomOU, Ou=AnotherOU, DC=Domain, Dc=local" -Filter * -Properties c,co,countrycode | Where-Object{$_.co -eq $null}
$users | Set-ADUser -Replace @{c="RO";co="Romania";countrycode=642}
```